# Laravel: Routing parameters not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have laravel on `localhost/laravel/public`. I am trying set routes but this always generate 404 error on url `localhost/laravel/public/user/John/any@mail.com`:

```
Route::get('user/{name}/{mail}', function($name, $mail)
{
    return "User $name : $mail";
});
```

and this work on url `localhost/laravel/public/test/John/any@mail.com`

```
Route::get('test/(:any)/(:any)', function($name, $mail)
{
    return "Test $name : $mail";
});
```

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using L3 (third version of Laravel) then your second way to handle routes is correct.

Routing with parameters in {} like so:

```
Route::get('user/{name}/{mail}', function($name, $mail)
```

won't work as it was introduced in Laravel 4.

Read more about routing in L3 in [here](http://three.laravel.com/docs/routing)

Comment: Read [here](http://laravel.com/docs/installation) about installing L4 - you can download it from github, BUT as from version 4 everything is handled by Composer. You can install composer and then install L4 from console - very handy :)

Comment: Don't be confused - whole laravel.com site is now dedicated to L4. The L3 docs are in link I gave you earlier